# C# Web application project File updating Issue on hosting provider server

Tags: asp.net, hosting

Hi I have created Web Form Application project and uploaded to hosting server provided by some hosting provider company. Every things code, Database connectivity are working fine. But I am facing strange issue when ever I do any changes in the codebehind files and upload files to server new functionality not works. Even sometimes I delete the code files old code still run on the webpage. I have written several emails to support team but they are not able to solve the issue( Not even able to understand the concer).

I also deleted my project from the server and uploaded dummy project just having line to display text on the label first time it works fine but when i update my cs file old text is always visible.

1) I have uploaded all the files inside the project folder.

2) I have not uploaded solution and web files found outside the project folder.

Does Any one have any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi every one I have solved the issue. I have created Web application project and every time I build my pages It will build DLL in bin directory. So after doing any changes I have to update my bin directory on the server too.